# Typescript declared static class method is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created an es6 library for some of my projects.

When I import this library all static functions raise an error.

This is an example.

My Class (es6) :

```js
class JsonSerializer {
    static toJson(node) { /* some code */ }
}

export default JsonSerializer
```

Typescript definition file :

```
export class JsonSerializer {
    static toJson(root: Node): any

    static fromJson(config: any): Node
}
```

I import my class like this

```
import {JsonSerializer} from 'ls-serializer'
```

When I try to use `toJson` static method.

And its give me following error :

```
_lsSerializer.JsonSerializer.toJson is not a function
```

I've same error for all static method.

Did I miss something ?

## EDIT

This is my library webpack config :

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry : {
        serializer : './src/serializer.js'
    },

    output : {
        path     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename : '[name].bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs-module'
    },

    resolve : {
        extensions : ['.js', '.jsx'],

        alias : {
            '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            '~' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'examples')
        }
    },

    devServer : {
        contentBase : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress    : true,
        port        : 9000
    },

    module : {
        rules : [{
            test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude : /node_modules/,
            loader  : 'babel-loader'
        }, {
            test : /\.(html)$/,
            use  : {
                loader  : 'html-loader',
                options : {
                    attrs : [':data-src']
                }
            }
        }]
    },

    devtool : 'source-map',

    mode : 'development'
};
```

And this is `./src/serializer.js`file code :

```js
import JsonSerializer from './serializers/JsonSerializer'

export {
    JsonSerializer, /* other exports*/
}
```

Comment: What is `_lsSerializer`? I mean, where is it coming from?

Comment: how are you trying to use `toJson` static method?

Comment: @briosheje This is an output when I try to run my unit tests with Jest. I've same error on browser console : `TypeError: ls_serializer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.JsonSerializer.toJson is not a function`

Comment: @Arfeo I import JsonSerializer and I call toJson method like this : `const res = JsonSerializer.toJson(currentNode)`.

Comment: Euuuuuh that's a weird import. Can you please share the webpack configuration and the package.json?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the problem and it's a little pitiful...

In my code toJson method is named `toJSON` with capitalize part... And in camel case in my typescript declaration file.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the file with the class is called `ls-serializer.ts`.

You have to use it like this:

```
import JsonSerializer from './ls-serializer'

JsonSerializer.toJson(...)
```

Or you can avoid `default`:

```
// ls-serializer.ts
export class JsonSerializer {
    static toJson(node) { /* some code */ }
}
```

And export the class like this:

```
import {JsonSerializer} from './ls-serializer'

JsonSerializer.toJson(...)
```

Comment: JsonSerializer class is in JsonSerializer.js file. ls-serializer is my library name. I added more information about my library on top.

Comment: @amiceli The import statement is still wrong, you have to import it without `{}` while exported with `default`.

Comment: I've edit my example, I think is less confusing now. I now difference between import with and without {}

Comment: @amiceli There is still `import {JsonSerializer}` in the question's code...